# auth error happen when I run the gtalk application based on gloox

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp

I run the xmpp application based on gloox to connect to gtalk on ubuntu, but it is not work, and the log information is such as:

```
`The server doesn't support any auth mechanisms we know about
```

what actually the problem is ? it must be some software need to support the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've got TLS support compiled in to Gloox.  For GTalk, you'll want to do start-TLS, then SASL PLAIN.